# SAS EG date convert dd/mm/yy to yy/mm/dd

Tags: sas

How can I convert dd/mm/yy/ to yy/mm/dd in SAS

I have 
ACCESS_DATE was something like: 18012019, but needs to be 2019/01/18
I did the following:

```
,put(ACCESS_DATE, YYMMDDS10.)   as 'ACCESS_DATE'n
```

but this creates: 18/01/2019

So how do I get the yyyy in the front like: yy/mm/dd in SAS EG

Comment: Are you sure ACCESS_DATE is a date variable and not either a character string or just a number that looks to you like a date but is really just `18,012,019`?

Comment: Dates are just numbers so 18,012,019 would be shown as *********. So it could be only an date String. But that should give an ERROR.

Answer (score 1):

In EG you might be selecting the format from a drop down list.  Double check the variable type (num or char) and format (several with y, m & d).

```
data _null_;

  date = '18-JAN-2019'd;

  put date            @15 'SAS date value';
  put date date9.     @15 'DATE9. format';
  put date date11.    @15 'DATE11. format';
  put date ddmmyyn8.  @15 'DDMMYYN8. format';

  put date YYMMDDS10. @15'YYMMDDS10. format';
  put date MMDDYYS10. @15'MMDDYYS10. format';
  put date DDMMYYS10. @15'DDMMYYS10. format'; 
run;
----- LOG -----
21567         SAS date value
18JAN2019     DATE9. format
18-JAN-2019   DATE11. format
18012019      DDMMYYN8. format     * possibly what you were seeing initially
2019/01/18    YYMMDDS10. format    * what is wanted
01/18/2019    MMDDYYS10. format    
18/01/2019    DDMMYYS10. format    * only way to get what is stated in question
```